# Create a new delete object_action in Symfony 1.4's admin generator

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, admin-generator

I'm using Symfony 1.4/Doctrine's admin generator.

There's a list of questions and I'd like to be able perform a custom object_action on each of them.

What I'm looking for is to mimic the `_delete` object action but doing some calculation before that.

So I created a new action :

```
  public function executeListDeleteAndRecalculate(sfWebrequest $request)
  {
    // Do the calculation

    // Then delete the question
  }
```

And I'm adding it to my generator.yml:

```
object_actions:
    delete_and_recalculate: ~
```

the new action shows in the admin generator but the delete part doesn't work.

I tried a bunch of thing to make it work:

- Once all the calculation was done, I first tried to redirect to the `questionActions/delete` action.
- I also tried to copy the `executeDelete` code to my new action.

But everytime I get the infamous

> 500 | Internal Server Error |
>   sfValidatorErrorSchema
>   _csrf_token [Required.]

So I'm guessing Symfony is doing some magic before actually deleting an object.

Do you know what I'm missing and **what's the best way to implement a deleteAndRecalculate kind of action?**

**Edit:**

Of course if I remove the `$request->checkCSRFProtection();` everything works just fine. But I assume it's pretty important so I'd like to find a prettier solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `delete` link from the admin generator uses a token to prevent CSRF attacks.

Basically, it sets a token into your session and into an hidden field of a form then checks them one against another on the request. This is possible because the `delete` link in the admin generator is actually a (javascript generated) form (this is done to add a `sf_method` hidden field to simulate REST behavior).

For more information on how CSRF works and can be prevented, you can read further on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

What you can do is use the same kind of link, you just have to pass a `method` parameter to `link_to` for it to generate a form, have a look at `lib/generator/sfModelGeneratorHelper.class.php` line 32 to see how it's done in the admin-gen.

You would then execute `$request->checkCSRFProtection()` in your `executeDeleteAndRecalculate` method, and proceed with whatever you want to do, including deleting the object by hand.

To properly generate the link, you would add a `linkToDeleteAndRecalculate` method in the Helper class of your module (that should lie in the `lib/${YourModule}GeneratorHelper.class.php` file of your module directory) and add the following code (directly taken and adapted from `sfModelGeneratorHelper`):

```
public function linkToDeleteAndRecalculate($object, $params)
{
  if ($object->isNew())
  {
    return '';
  }

  return '<li class="sf_admin_action_delete">'.link_to(__($params['label'], array(), 'sf_admin'), 'delete_and_recalculate', $object, array('method' => 'delete', 'confirm' => !empty($params['confirm']) ? __($params['confirm'], array(), 'sf_admin') : $params['confirm'])).'</li>';
}
```

Please note that you have to change the route (I've put `delete_and_recalculate` by default but you might want to prefix it with your module's name) from the `link_to` call.

You can then use your `delete_and_recalculate` nearly like a builtin method from the admin generator (and pass it a label from the `generator.yml` for example)

Now that was the hard-way.

The easy way would be to subscribe to the `admin.delete_object` event, from your module's pre-execute for example, and to your job there :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
However, even if I try to copy the way linkToDelete creates a link, I can't generate the onclick javascript event that is creating the form. And I can't find where it's done for the _delete object action either.

About the "easy way": I don't think that would work since I want to keep the default "Delete" action too.

Comment: Ok, I have edited my answer with directions on how to generate the link, does that help?

Comment: I'm almost there, everything seems to be ok until i click on the link. i don't know what's wrong about the route i wrote (see here: http://pastie.org/798862 ) in backend/config/routing.yml. But I get a 404 "Action "supprimer_et_recalculer/33" does not exist."

Comment: Do you have the default /:module/:action route still in your routing.yml?

If yes, and if it is before your custom route, then symfony will match it in priority.

If not, well, the complete trace could help, as well as your complete routing.yml I guess :-)